# Trouble Connecting Django Application to PostgreSQL Database Running in Docker Container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, python-venv

I'm currently working on a Django project where I'm using a virtual environment (venv) to run Django locally on my machine (Windows). Additionally, I have a PostgreSQL database running in a Docker container.

I'm encountering issues trying to establish a connection between my Django application and the PostgreSQL database. Whenever I attempt to run python manage.py makemigrations, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': connection to server at "host.docker.internal" (141.31.78.207), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

  warnings.warn(
No changes detected
```

Here are the relevant portions of my Django settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'SilverSurfer',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': "root",
        'HOST': "host.docker.internal",
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

And here's my Docker Compose file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15.0
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: SilverSurfer
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db.sql
```

It's worth noting that my Docker container for the database is running:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          
528ad4e3232f   postgres:15.0   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   37 minutes ago   Up 37 minutes   
PORTS                    NAMES
0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   02_db-db-1
```

I've tried connecting to the PostgreSQL database using psql, but I receive a similar timeout error.

Could someone please assist me in troubleshooting this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I experimented also with alternative hostnames such as "localhost", "0.0.0.0", and even my local IP address obtained from ipconfig ("172.16.98.1"). I encountered similar timeout errors.

Originally, I planned to have two separate Docker containers - one for Django and another for PostgreSQL. However, I encountered difficulties in establishing communication between the Django container and the PostgreSQL container. This setup also resulted in connection issues, preventing Django from connecting to the PostgreSQL database in the other Docker container.
With two Docker containers I also tried to create a network and specify the container name of the Postgre container in the Django DB settings, but that didn't work either.

Full trace from error message trying with `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`:

```
(myenv) PS C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend> python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line       
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 156, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 313, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 330, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 306, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 91: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 1):

Press `Win + I` to open the system settings. Click Network & Internet from the menu options. In the next window, select Status on the left-hand side pane.

Click Change adapter options to open the Network Connections tool.

```
Ethernet or WiFI > Properties > IPv4 Address of your machine.
```

[image]

or

Type `ipconfig /all` in CMD and press Enter. This will show all the information about your network adapter: Physical Address: This is the MAC address of your network adapter. DHCP Enabled: Indicates if the network connection is using DHCP or Static IP Address

Do Not Use Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter IP Address.
Replace

> host.docker.internal
> with the IP address of your local machine on your WIFI/LAN network. *192.168.1.111* IP is of my LAN Network which is connected to My DSL.

[image]

use that `IP:PORT(DB) Eg 192.168.1.111:5432` to connect with postgres DB

Comment: I tried it like this `'HOST': "172.27.160.1:5432"` in the Django settings.py, but it was not working. Got this error: `could not translate host name "172.27.160.1:5432" to address`.

I also noticed that in  `ipconfig /all` I have this label for the Ethernet adapter: `Ethernet-Adapter vEthernet (WSL (Hyper-V firewall))`.
So maybe it could be because of the firewall.

Comment: I have deactivated the Hyper-V firewall and tried it again but it is still not working.

Comment: Do Not Use Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter IP Address.

Replace "host.docker.internal" with the IP address of your local machine on your WIFI/LAN network.

192.168.1.111 IP is of my LAN  Network which is connected to My DSL.

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting from the host machine to the docker container. You don't need to (and should not) use the address `host.docker.internal`.

```
        'HOST': "host.docker.internal",
```

Since you are publishing the port already,

```
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

it's enought to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as the `HOST` in this case.

```
        'HOST': "localhost",
```

Note that if you later on change the application code also to a container and start it from the same compose file, the correct host is then `db` (the service name for the database).

Comment: I deleted the container and the venv folder and set everything up again and tried with 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' but it still doesn't work. But this time I got a different error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
...
  File "C:\Users\Abdul\Software_Projekte\SilverSurfer\04_Backend\myenv\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 91: invalid start byte

Comment: @user23705833 Please add the full trace by editing the original question also.

Comment: Though it seems that that error might not be related to the connection at all.

Comment: I added it above